# How to remove SnapShot listener (Firestore - Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
func addUserObserver(_ update: @escaping () -> Void) {
    FriendSystem.system.USER_REF.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
        self.userList.removeAll()

        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error retreiving collection")
            return
        }
        for document in snapshot!.documents {
            let email =  document.get("email") as! String
            if email != Auth.auth().currentUser?.email! {
                self.userList.append(User(userEmail: email, userID: document.documentID))
            }
            update()
        }
    }
}
```

I have added a listener but can't figure out how to disconnect/remove it. Thanks!

Comment: Your need to add a var to track the listener like this `let listener = FriendSystem.system...` and then later to remove it, use `listener.remove()`. It's covered in the Firestore Documentation [Detach a listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As shown in the documentation on [detaching a listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener), you need to keep the value you get back from `addSnapshotListener`:

```
var listener = FriendSystem.system.USER_REF.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
    ...
```

And then later you can remove the listener with:

```
listener.remove()
```

Comment: Great answer, and you beat me to it.

Comment: Thanks @Frank Vank Puffelen but when I do `func removeUserListner() { listener.remove()}` I get the error Use of unresolved identifier 'listener'

Comment: That means you've defined `listener` as a scope that `removeUserListner` can't reach it at. If `removeUserListner` is a method in the same class, you'll want `listener` to be a field of that same class for example.